# T.join(100) completion time

Tags: java

If I write a code block like this, in main method:

```
while(t.isAlive()){
 t.join(100);
}
```

Isn't it that join() extends every single time the loop executes and the main thread will wait till the completion of thread

```
t
```

Comment: ["This implementation uses a loop of this.wait calls conditioned on this.isAlive"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join(long)) Looks like you wouldn't need the explicit conditional.

Comment: "...extends every single time the loop executes..." Which loop? There's no loop in the code you posted.

Comment: @jesper: please have a look now

Comment: As you have it now, you can just as well replace the whole loop with: `t.join();` (without a timeout). There's no purpose to do this in a `while` loop, with a timeout of 100ms for each call to `join`.

Comment: @Jesper: can you enlighten me why does official Java doc uses such a loop here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/simple.html

Comment: @RajatSaxena as you can see in that example, it does more inside the loop than just call `t.join(...)` again, and it stops waiting after some time. Note that `t.join()` without an argument will wait forever.